# Media Queries not working on desktop

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I am having a strange problem with my media queries.  They seem to be working just fine on my mobile devices, but when I resize my desktop browser the changes are not applied.  This makes using web inspector/firebug impossible to inspect my mobile styles.  Here is my media query:

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are calling **device specific** queries. If you want to test on browser window resize, you need to remove `-device-` from both min and max calls.

`@media only screen
and (min-width: 320px) 
and (max-width: 480px) {}`

Comment: You'd be surprised how long I've been searching for a fix to this, apparently I had some selectors with `-device-`. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Alkarin right on! I'm glad this is still helping people!