# Different results when reducing browser width directly and when reducing in chrome device toolbar

Tags: html, css

Here is the result when i reducing browther width to 740px. No scrollbar;
[image]
Same width but in chrome device toolbar
[image]
Now scrollbar appears.
This happened because i'm using negative right margins in some blocks, but i also using

```
body { overflow-x: hidden }
```

to prevent scroll. It works perfect until i turn on chrome device toolbar. What is the reason of this behavior? Should i don't use negative margins?

Comment: _“What is the reason of this behavior? Should i don't use negative margins?”_ - first of all, you should _not_ just show images, and expect us to figure out what is going wrong. Please go read [ask], and how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

I was having a similar issue, and found an answer that may help you [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20432121/media-queries-not-working-on-desktopy)

For me the issue was the Media queries I was using looked like this:

`@media only screen and (max-device-width: 600px) {...}`

The `-device-` part of the selector, ensures your CSS is only being applied to mobile devices. Consequentially, the ***chrome device toolbar*** is used specifically to test CSS on **mobile** devices, which is probably why you are seeing the css applied properly there, but not when you resize your browser window on its own.

Try removing `-device-` from your media queries to instead look like this:

`@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {...}`

Which should apply your CSS changes on both **mobile devices and desktop.**

---

Also make sure you have the following code in your HTML header, to ensure the viewport is configured properly:

`<meta content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" name="viewport">`

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

chrome tool is for **mobile device testing**. it actually display mostly same in mobile device. without chrome tool it will display for desktop browser compatibility.chrome tool

so chrome tool actually gives the view mostly same as mobile device.
for mobile view testing it's better to use chrome tool for responsive mode.

chrome tool uses **User Agent**. 
The User Agent Type, or Device Type, setting let's you change the type of the device. Possible values are:

**Mobile**

**Desktop**

**Desktop with touch**