# CSS Media query not working in stylesheet

Tags: html, css

I have checked similar questions and what seems to be missing in their code is:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Now, I have this code already but CSS media query still seems not to work.

This is my style sheet:

```
.calculator__container {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 40vw;
    margin-right: 40vw;
    margin-top: 25vw;
    padding-top: 40px;
    box-shadow: -9px 4px 21px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}

#clear {
    background-color: red;
    color: white;

};

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 500px) {
    .calculator__container {
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-radius: 3px;
        padding: 5px;
        text-align: center;
        margin-left: 10vw;
        margin-right: 10vw;
        margin-top: 25vw;
        padding-top: 40px;
        color: blue;
        box-shadow: -9px 4px 21px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    };
    #clear {
        background-color: red;
        color: pink;

    }
}
```

Can I get any help, please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Media Queries not working on desktop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20432121/media-queries-not-working-on-desktop)

Comment: @disinfor unfortunately not. I have changed from max-device-width to max-width but still the same issue.

Comment: Try `@media (max-width: 500px)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Use `max-width` instead of `max-device-width`. Device width is dependent on the width of the device, not the browser window, as such will not alter when you resize your browser window if viewed on a desktop screen at 1920 x 1080 for example as the max-device-width will remain constant at 1920px.

```css
.calculator__container {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 40vw;
    margin-right: 40vw;
    margin-top: 25vw;
    padding-top: 40px;
    box-shadow: -9px 4px 21px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}

#clear {
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .calculator__container {                     
        margin-left: 10vw;
        margin-right: 10vw;      
        color: blue;
    }
    #clear {
        color: pink;
    }
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<div class="calculator__container">
  
  Calculator container.
  
</div>

<div id="clear">
  
  Clear.
  
</div>
```

```css
.calculator__container {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 20vw;
    margin: 25vh auto 0 auto; /* top, right, bottom, left */
    padding-top: 40px;
    box-shadow: -9px 4px 21px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}

#clear {
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .calculator__container {                     
        width: 80vw;     
        color: blue;
    }
    #clear {
        color: pink;
    }
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<div class="calculator__container">
  
  Calculator container.
  
</div>

<div id="clear">
  
  Clear.
  
</div>
```

Comment: It is still not working. Still having the exact issues

Comment: I'll like to ask if you tried it in your console because it is still not working from here.

Comment: @MarvellousAdesanya if you want your `.calculator__container` element to take up 80% of the viewport width, set `width: 80vw;` you can remove the left and right margins. Likewise in your initial rule, you can set `width: 20vw;` and remove the left and right margins. Edit: set the left and right margins to auto to center the element.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me. I find it weird though since I have done other projects without including the `min-width`:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {

}
```